# Посоветуйте что-нибудь для xml в java

Tags: java, xml, методы

С помощью каких методов в java реализуется поиск по тегу в xml файле? И вот я допустим нашел нужный мне тег, а потом с пом. какого метода вытащить значение из него? Или посоветуйте пожалуйста книгу по этому вопросу. В интернете только какие то примеры, которые мне не очень подходят.

Xml-файл допустим вот такой.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Lift>
    <variables>
        <variable value = "25"/>
        <variable value = "30"/>
    </variables>
</Lift>
```

Comment: `DocumentBuilderFactory` в помощь.

Comment: StAX, SAX парсеры.

Comment: Нужно написать точно чем не устроили примеры в интернете. А то люди щас накопируют сюда как раз те примеры, которые Вас не устраивают.

Comment: Ну так в книге или рекомендации XML тоже будет другой, но принципы останутся те же. Думаю, что если Вы уже пробовали написать код, то стоит попробовать разобраться с ошибками в нем. Для уроков StackOverflow плохо подходит.

Comment: @антонсорокин Правильно будет `<variables><variable value = "25"/>
        <variable value = "30"/></variables>` у тебя же переменн**ЫЕ** внутри, а не одна

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , а что если блоков будет 2 или еще будут 2 блока и разные переменные, тогда что? Не фертити. Так проще.. И понятнее, чем говоришь ты.

Comment: @And блок хотя бы смысл будет передавать. можно там написать и `sdfhsdgsdhj`, только вот кому от этого будет проще?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, да допустим, в авто-генерациях, которые собирают пользователи. Чем не вариант?

Comment: @And ну, в принципе, если всё делать через пятую точку - да, вполне себе вариант

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, ну скорей всего, для пятой точки и делает :D

Comment: @And а в случае `что если блоков будет 2 или еще будут 2 блока и разные переменные, тогда что?` - для этого придумали такую магию, как **атрибуты**. ........ну если для пятой точки - то сойдет) там любой вариант подойдет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как вариант, заюзать `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

```
 public Document parse(final File file) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false);
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(file);
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
        log.error("XMLParser: Error loading file " + file, e);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

Ну, а дальше по дереву бегать и дергать нужные элементы.

```
final Document doc = parse(new File("xml.xml"));
    for (Node n = doc.getFirstChild(); n != null; n = n.getNextSibling()) {
        for (Node d = n.getFirstChild(); d != null; d = d.getNextSibling()) {
            for (Node m = d.getFirstChild(); m != null; m =m.getNextSibling()) {
                if ("variable".equals(m.getNodeName())) {
                    final String value = m.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue().trim();
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

на коленке начиркал, а так, можно сделать рекурсию, в обход всех тегов и аттрибутов.

Comment: в консоль выводится variable 2 раза, а мне надо именно 25 и 30.
P.S.
Точнее вы ответили на первый вопрос, а как мне вытащить значения оттуда?

Comment: @антон сорокин, дак я думал, сам додумаешься. Поправил ответ.

Comment: пасиб. Кстати, почему ты обьявил отдельный метод, а не написал 
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document doc = db.parse(new File("xml.xml"));

Comment: @антон сорокин и что постоянно писать это? Малоли, где, это потребуется, постоянно писать в трайкатчах не ауе. - Проще методом и отслеживать все ошиюки в нем, где угодно дернуть, можно в статик завернуть, еще проще будет.

Comment: @антонсорокин, не совсем понял вопроса, ну если вы имеете в виду аттрибуты, то метод `getNamedItem` - в котором указываем название аттрибута., а если вы про название тегов, то тут как бы `getNodeName` вместе с `equals`.